# How can equations have no solutions if an equation states that two mathematical expressions are the same object

Tags: logic, terminology

If an equation claims that the two side of the equation are equal, how can there be equations with no solution?

$$
x=1+x
$$

Here the equation states that $x$ is equal to $1+x$ but the equation has no solutions.

Comment: Equations can be wrong.

Comment: But the equation asserts that $x$ is identical to $1+x$, how is that wrong? @JonathanZ

Comment: There are no real (or complex) numbers for which $x=1+x$. So if your equation is supposed to have a real solution, then it is wrong.   If you want to know how many solutions it has then the answer is zero.

Comment: If I claim "Dogs are Fish" what is the solution to that?  The only way I can claim "Dogs are fish" is if I am lying.   Likewise if I claim "$x = 1 + x$" then I am claiming that $x$ and $1 +x$ are the same thing.  Well, I can *say* that.  But I would be lying because it is impossible for something and one more than that thing to be the same thing.

Comment: First of all, equations don't assert things. You should add some quantifiers to be making a clear assertion. Once you do that, please see @Henry 's comment.

Comment: You can have identities like $x^2=x\cdot x$ which are indeed equal to one another or equations to solve for $x$ like $2^x=1$, but the second is not equal for all $x$. $x=x+1$ does not mean both sides are equal to one another for all $x$, but rather you are trying to solve for possible $x$ that satisfy the equation. In this case, there are no $x$ that satisfy the equation.

Comment: Also, "I am the king of England". How is that wrong?

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to "$0 = 1$", which I hope you will agree is a false assertion. So your equation, being equivalent to it, is also a false assertion.

Comment: @JonathanZ Depends. Your Majesty, is that you? :p

Comment: Seeing how this discussion has evolved, this is probably a better question for the [Philosophy stack](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut - I appreciate you showing proper respect. Swing by the castle next time you're in London and we'll arrange some sort of knight-thingie for you. I'll also show you the Royal $x$, which happens to be equal to one plus itself. 

Comment: Now that it can be explained that $x=x+1$ is not possible if $x$ is a number, one may wonder whether it's possible in other contexts. Mathematics are flexible, you may redefine any of $x$, $1$, $=$ or $+$. See for instance [tropical geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry) for nonstandard definitions of addition and multiplication.

Comment: Heck, there are solutions in cardinal arithmetic, and even in the fussier ordinal arithmetic.

Comment: Considering the question , it makes little sense to come with the exotics like cardinal numbers. The first few comments clarified the issue , from some point on it will only confuse the author since I doubt he/she has heard of cardinal numbers. I admit I never heard of "tropical geometry" which seems to be even weirder.

Comment: @Peter - Yeah, I only mentioned it as a simpler alternative than tropical geometry. But both are probably out of scope for the question.

Comment: @Peter The goal is not to confuse the OP, and I don't expect he'll be going deeper into the details. Still, it's good to know that it's permitted to play with definitions (as long as what you get makes *some* sense). I didn't think of cardinals and ordinals, good idea - and there *are* simple and funny explanations, see the [Hilbert Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).

Comment: @JonathanZ : That's a very astute observation, +1. It is certainly true that $\omega = 1 + \omega$.

Comment: @MPW - What I find even more fun is that if the question had used $x=x+1$, there would no longer be any solutions in the ordinals. (That's why I call them "fussier".)

Answer (score 4):

Equations are simply statements. Statements can be false.

In addition, an equation does not assert the existence or nonexistence of its solutions. Your equation is a statement $P(x)$ that might be true or false **depending on the value of** $x$. As it happens, $P(x)$ is false for all $x$ in this case, so there is no solution (no value of $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true).

Comment: So if I claim that $x=y$ I assert that they are **excatly** the same object.
And an equation is a statement that claim that both sides are exactly the same object.
What is the difference?

Comment: But the assertion that they are exactly the same object is false.

Comment: Assertions are not facts. Try asserting "my bank balance equals one million dollars" and see if the bank will let you withdraw that balance.

Comment: "So if I claim that x=y I assert that they are excatly the same object. And an equation is a statement that claim that both sides are exactly the same object. What is the difference?"  There is no difference.  If you claim $x = y$, why should I believe you?  How do *you* know you are correct.  Let suppose I said $17 = 6$ and you said "wait that's wrong" and I said "How can it be wrong?  I just said it."  ... well that's the same thing.

Comment: So if a question in mathematics tells you that $x=y$ would you say that it is wrong? @fleablood

Comment: @mawaior I would ask ‘could you clarify on the exact relationship between $x$ and $y$, before asking me to infer the truthiness of the statement?’

Comment: Okay, that's a declaration.  Unless it's impossible we should assume it is true to the best of the narrators knowledge.  But it might be an impossible declaration.

Comment: @mawaior Some definitions are equations, but not all equations are definitions.

Comment: If a question in mathematics instead tells to that assume (in the contextual space of the question) it already being given that $x=y$, I’d be happy to do so. I think you are confusing between given statements (which are assumed true in the context of the question), and question statements (for which you’d have to infer their truthiness) @mawaior

Comment: We can declare $x$ to be anything.  But if the thing we declare is impossible then there is no solution.   "Let $x$ be an even prime larger than $37$" is a perfectly valid thing to say aloud (I *just* said it).  But that will yield an impossibility and "no solution".  Likewise "Let $x = x+1$" is valid thing to say that yields an impossible $0=1$ and no solution.  Or I could declare "Let $x = \frac {x^2}2 -2$" and have that yield a *possible* $x=2$ or $x=-2$.  We, in solving, are essentially saying "If what you are saying is true, I conclude.."

Comment: "So if a question in mathematics tells you that x=y would you say that it is wrong?". I'm going to be a crank here, and repeat my comment that I made on the original question: Equations with variables that aren't quantified (or for which a solution set is not requested) are not assertions.

Answer (score 1):

If you say, in this example, that $x$ and $x+1$ are the "exact same object" (let's say we are talking in the context of polynomials), then in particular they satisfy all the same properties, so they should also map every number to the same number. But $0 + 1 = 1 \neq 0$.

The assertion "$x$ and $x+1$ are the same object" is false.